# Put HTML in a DataTable?

Tags: html, vb.net, datatable

In vb.net I have a DataTable that I am adding content to. One column contains a free text field so I want to show the new lines as new lines on the page. I did this:

```
For Each row As DataRow In dtEmails.Rows
    Dim newBody As String = row.Item("body").ToString.Replace(vbCrLf, "<br>")
    row.Item("body") = newBody
Next
```

But the cells now just show literal HTML like `Line<br>Line`. One forum thread I found suggested calling `Server.HtmlDecode` on the string but that doesn't work. Is there another way?

Comment: Try using "<br />" instead of "<br>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer to this - calling `Server.HtmlDecode` as each row is bound.

```
Protected Sub myGridView_RowDataBound(ByVal o As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvEmails.RowDataBound
    Dim cell As String = e.Row.Cells(8).Text.Replace(vbCrLf, "<br>")
    e.Row.Cells(8).Text = Server.HtmlDecode(cell)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a VB.net guy but I hear [HTMLAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) helps with issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

... Your arguments are the wrong way around - Try this:

```
Dim newBody As String = row.Item("body").ToString.Replace("<br>", vbCrLf)
```

Hope that does the trick

Comment: No the arguments are correct - I'm trying to replace new lines with the HTML line break tag.